# Assigning the contents of XPath result from Playwright into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright, playwright-python

Using Playwright, the code below successfully prints the title of stackoverflow.co. This works because the Xpath query (//title) produces only ONE result (there is only one title).

```
page.goto("https://stackoverflow.co")
    
page_text = page.locator("//title").text_content()
print(page_text)
```

In the code below I am attempting to store the contents of all the paragraph tags into a list (not a string). Below does not work, because the XPath query produces MULTIPLE results (in contrast to the previous example).

```
page.goto("https://stackoverflow.co/")
    
page_text = page.locator("//p").text_content()
```

How do you store the results (plural) of a single XPath query into a single Python list?

Comment: What do you mean by "results"? Do you mean all text contents? `page.locator("//p").all_text_contents()`

Comment: @ggorlen, yes, this was incredibly simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### You can simply do as below: (JavaScript)

```
 const list = await page.locator('locator').allTextContents()
 console.log("The Paragraphs List: => "+ list)
```